# ZeroMQ in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, zeromq

I'm trying to deploy an Azure web role that uses ZeroMQ. In my local machine, everything works great, but when I deploy it, I get the following error:

```
Unable to load DLL 'libzmq': The specified module could not be found
```

I have marked the dll's build property as "content", and I can see it in the package being created. Anything that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It turns out that the latest libzmq is built using VS2010, so it depends on VC++ 2010 run time. Azure instances doesn't have them by default, so you need to make your roles install the dependency before starting up.

Answer (score 0):

Click the DLL file and set its "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy Always".
You can verify that the DLL is being copied to the cloud by extracting and examining your .cspkg file (You can rename it to .zip and extract it).

Also make sure the DLL is compiled as 64-bit or else it won't run in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the sample shown here [Pub/Sub with ZeroMQ on Azure](http://coderead.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/pubsub-with-zeromq-on-azure/)